# How to provide an EditorTemplate for IEnumerable<MyModel>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-editor-templates

Is it possible to provide an Editor Template for IEnumerable (Or IList, List, MyModel[], for that matter)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old post but what you can do is make a template called `MyModelList` that takes `IEnumerable<MyModel>` and then you can have a `Html.EditorFor(x => x.MyModelList, "MyModelList")`